# Is there a function to unhide columns in excel through python

Tags: python, dataframe, styleframe

I have an Excel spreadsheet which is converted to a `DataFrame` using `StyleFrame` to keep color formatting. When I convert this `DataFrame` back to an Excel spreadsheet, a few columns are already hidden by default. This is my code:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler, utils  
sf = StyleFrame.read_excel("aaaa\\aaaa\\cdddd .xlsx",sheet_name = 2, read_style=True, header = None)
ew = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter('aaaa\\abbbbbb2.xlsx')
sf.to_excel(excel_writer = ew, header = False, index = False).save()
```

How do do make sure these columns are not hidden when opening the spreadsheet in Excel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your code doing that is unexpected? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Are you sure? what version of StyleFrame are you using? I can't reproduce this. If I'm reading a sheet with hidden columns and immediately saving it, the column is **not** hidden in the new file.

Answer (score 0):

**Excel file :**

```
df.to_excel('demofile.xlsx',index=False)

import openpyxl

py = openpyxl.load_workbook('demofile.xlsx')
exlsheet = py.get_sheet_by_name('yoursheetName')
```

**Checking Column**

```
for col in exlsheet.columns:
  if not col[2].value:
    exlsheet.column_dimensions[col[2].column].hidden = True
```

**Save your file**

```
py.save('modifiedfile.xlsx')
```